# Ingresar sólo mayúsculas

Tags: javascript, input, funcion

tengo un problema con mi código. Necesito que en el input la persona sólo pueda digitar letras mayúsculas. No se en que estoy errando...

```js
function valoresPermitidos(){

    document.getElementById('#letra00').addEventListener('keyup',function(){

        this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();

    },true);

}
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="20" id="letra00">
```

Comment: Pues nunca estás agregando el evento al input porque nunca llamas a la función `valoresPermitidos`. La declaras pero nunca la invocas. Por otro lado, `getElementById` no necesita el prefijo `#`. Invoca a la función después de su declaración para que funcione:  `valoresPermitidos()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas.

- Nunca se agrega el eventListener porque el código está dentro de una función que no llamas.
- `getElementById` recibe como parámetro el id del elemento. El signo **#** está demás. Sí necesitas el signo cuando usas `querySelector`.

Arreglado te queda así:

```js
    
document.getElementById('letra00').addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()
});
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="20" id="letra00">
```

Comment: Cierto. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!. Estaba acostumbrado a usar querySelector por eso utilice mal el símbolo y lo de la función es verdad en ningún momento la estaba invocando. Veo que todavía me falta un largo camino para aprender a programar. Gracias de nuevo!.